# Flutter: Issue while converting json to model using json_serializable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety, json-serializable

Suppose there are two models **User** and **City**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
    int id;
    String name;
    City? city;
}

@JsonSerializable()
class City {
   int id;
   String name;
}
```

Now suppose during API call, we've got a user model but in the city object model, we only get **id** not **name**. Something like this

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Matthew",
    "city": {
        "id": 12
    }
}
```

But due to the default nature of json_serializable and json_annotation.
This JSON is not mapped to the User model, during mapping, it throws the exception.
*type Null is not a subtype of type String. (because here **name** key is missing in city object)*

But as we already declared in the User object that City is optional, I wanted that it should parse the User JSON with city as null.

Any help or solution would be really appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for ignoring a certain field only while serializing or only while deserializing. You can either ignore both or none. However, there is a workaround that I use.

1. Make a global method in your model file that just returns null like this:

```
T? toNull<T>(_) => null;
```

2. Inside your `User` model add a custom `JsonKey` for City:

```
@JsonKey(fromJson: toNull, includeIfNull: false)
City? City;
```

What this does is when converting from Json it uses your specificed function for converting `city` and replaces your value with null. Then due to `includeIfNull` property it just skips parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Abdur, but don't you think that it should be the default behavior of json_serializable?. I've used Unbox library for iOS development and It works just like that.

Comment: @HimanshuArora i guess it isn't default behavior because nullable values doesn't mean it will always be null and there could scenarios where the user wants to parse the incoming json which can contain a key for this null value for. e.g. User favourites.

Comment: Also I guess the json_serializable would have ignored City if your json didn't contain a key for it. Although I'm not sure because I've never tested such a situation.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by that. Post it as a different question if you want to parse a list. @HimanshuArora